# Dynamically adding TestClasses to TestNG at runtime

Tags: testng

We have a conditional looping requirement to run a Test say Test1 in A.class depending upon the output/return value of another Test say Test2 in B.class.
Also, this is to be done in a loop i.e till the time the return value of Test2 in B.class matches user specified criteria, we need to run Test1 in A.class.

So basically, running of Test1 in A.class is dynamic i.e at runtime.

We did look at the Factory option but that doesn't seem to solve the issue as Factory involves dynamically creating required no. of objects of a Test class before we run testng.
Here we need to run these methods as per execution output when TestNG runs them.

Can you please let us know if this support is provided by TestNG or would we need to implement this logic in our Test classes itself.

Thanks
Neha

Answer (score 1):

It's technically not possible to add classes to the classpath at runtime, by design.

What you can do is always run that test method but then have it do nothing if a certain condition is not met.